# Does ArrayList in C# can contain objects various types?

Tags: c#, arraylist

Is it possible, to do something like that:

```
ArrayList arl = new ArrayList();
arl.Add(1);
arl.Add("test");

int[,] tab = new int[4, 4];
init(tab);

arl.Add(tab);
```

Is it possible to contain objects of various types (Like in JavaScript or Lua)? (C#)

Comment: Does this give a compile error? `ArrayList` contains objects

Comment: try to run to see how C# compiler react

Comment: Did you tried at least once? I don't see any effort here..

Comment: Look at this already discussed
[Objects in ArrayList]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367524/c-sharp-objects-in-arraylists

Comment: You should ask yourself why you need to do this. Rarely would you need to in a statically typed language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ArrayList contains elements of type object so this means you can put everything in it. When retrieving it again, you can then case it back to its original type.
Of course, due to this casting it's less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  ArrayList stores a collection of the type `object` meaning you can insert any `.NET` type.

You should really use `List<T>`.  For example:

```
 List<int> listIntegers = new List<int>();
 listIntegers.Add(1);
```

You could also use `List<object>` however you will have to unbox all of the items in the list. Which potentially may incur performance issues.

Comment: This would appear to be a random downvoter. I've just had the two questions I asked here downvoted for no particular reason.. :/

Comment: I have had it before, you can send a mail to stack overflow to act on this.

Answer (score 0):

As for your question, yes `ArrayList` can contain various object types.
 It is generally recommended by Microsoft to use `List<T>` instead, to prevent the need of boxing and unboxing to Type `object` when using the same types.

If you have a recurring pattern of types it might be more helpful (and faster) to define a custom class:

```
protected class arl_items
{
   public string item1 {get; set;};
   public int item2 {get; set;};
   public int[4,4] item3 {get; set;};
}
```

and then go:

```
List<arl_items> arl = new List<arl_items>();
```

But if there is *no pattern* to your value-types you can as well use `ArrayList`, because creating `List<object>` would be meaningless, as they are the same.

Just btw. i prefer using `List<object>` over ArrayList, but that is only my personal preference

Comment: ..perhaps clarify your use of a generic `List<object>` here. I would downvote your answer but I am not sure if you are saying an `ArrayList` and `List<object>` are essentially identical (which, they are), or you're saying to use a `List<object>` instead of an `ArrayList` (which is pointless).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead thanks, i wasn't aware that i mixed my personal preferences into the answer too much

Answer (score 0):

You can have diffent types in a `ArrayList`
try this:

```
var ary = new ArrayList();

ary.Add("some string");
ary.Add(23.4);
ary.Add(new StringBuilder());
ary.Add("some other string");
```

You can then query it like this:

```
string[] strings = ary.OfType<string>();
StringBuilder[] stringBuilders = ary.OfType<StringBuilder>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it can since it does not do any type checking, it *can sometimes* be faster than a `List<T>` when working with reference types, though it is generally not recommended to use it when you have a perfectly fine type safe alternative.

Any type that inherits from `object` can be stored in an `ArrayList`. Whenever you access an item in an `ArrayList` you must be careful to cast it to the correct type or else you will get a compiler error.

I believe `ArrayList` is an old relic from the days before generic types in .Net

Comment: What? ... you're incorrect. In fact, when casting objects back out it will be slower due to runtime type checking..

Comment: Depends on what you're storing in the arraylist, for reference types ArrayList is actually a little faster (by a negligible amount to be fair), tested by adding reference type to arraylist over 1000000 iterations and confirmed. On the other hand, adding to a `List<int>` is significantly faster than adding to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I think I've read your answer wrong. The way I interpreted it, you were saying that an `ArrayList` always performs faster than a `List<class>`.. is that not what you meant?

Comment: No that's not what i meant, i suppose i could have worded it a little differently, i'll edit my post to clear some things up