# How to access arraylist?

Tags: c#, list

I am having list method like this    **testing**   is the class having theree

```
 public ArrayList converttolist(string commandText, CommandType commandType)
    {
        ArrayList Listlines = new ArrayList();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = commandText;
        cmd.CommandType = commandType;
        cmd.Connection = obj_con.getconection();
        try
        {

            cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                testing ts = new testing();

                var alldata = new state_testingCLS.testing();

                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    ts.id_11 = Convert.ToInt64(sdr["id_11"]);
                    ts.countryid = Convert.ToInt64(sdr["countryid"]);
                    ts.state = Convert.ToString(sdr["state"]);
                    Listlines.Add((ts));
                }
                sdr.Close();
            }

            return Listlines;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

In a **listlines** i have to fetch records but i don't have any idea about this one please help me on this one

Now if i access it

```
ArrayList aa= cls.getAll();
                foreach (state_testingCLS.testing Txt in aa)
                {


                    string aa1 = Txt.state.ToString();

                }
```

Same data returns every time

Comment: Check updated @NitinVarpe

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem but you are inserting `alldata` but never set any property on it. Did you mean to insert `ts`? (`Listlines.Add(ts)`)

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake @ClaudioRedi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate class

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Int64 id_11 { get; set; }
public Int64 countryid { get; set; }
public string state { get; set; }
}
```

In method

```
 Ilist<MyClass> myclassList=new List<MyClass>();
```

After that you can assign field to new object of this class and add that to list

```
myclassList.Add(new MyClass(){
    id_11=ts.id_11,
    countryid =ts.countryid,
    state =ts.state
});
```

You can then change return type of method to `IList<MyClass>`

**Updated**

try with

```
for(int i = 0; i < aa.Length; i++)
{
       var obj=(testing)aa[i]
}
```

then fetch values from obj

Comment: Ok i understood this one but my problem is how to fetch this one and i am using separate method for this one so i can not use it with return type

Comment: didnt get u, cant u use looping over Ilist

Comment: But i have a method with will return whole array list and then i have to read that array list

Comment: i dont know why u r stuck on ArrayList check first answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367524/c-sharp-objects-in-arraylists

Comment: I have data in `Listlines` but i can not access it
Its return null

Comment: Have u tried first casting object in ArrayList to ur class testing myObject = (testing )Txt ;

Comment: nitin how to divide this type of data?  `List<state_testingCLS> aa = cls.getAll();` in this there is data and i want it in a for loop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45469/discussion-between-dholakiyaankit-and-nitin-varpe)

Comment: Done thanku very very much not exactly what i want but it helps