# Store this in a Array List

Tags: c#

I want to store Product objects in a array list. Below is the definition of the product class.

```
    class Product
    {
       public string name;
       public int iD;
       public int price;

       public void addProduct()
       {   
          Console.WriteLine("Enter Name : ");
          name = Console.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine("Enter ID : ");
          iD = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          Console.WriteLine("Enter Price : ");
          price = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       }
    }
```

Comment: You either mean array, list or arraylist. Which do you mean? _If you mean arraylist, then that is a bad decision._

Comment: yes I want to store this data in ArrayList and whenever I take input from user I want to store data in the next index nd so on

Comment: Don't use an arraylist. Use a `List<Product>`. Call `Add` on it.

Comment: And name it AddProduct(). Standard C# convention.

Comment: why using arraylist is not a good choice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063156/why-isnt-arraylist-marked-obsolete

Comment: @MubMalik "*why using arraylist is not a good choice?*" => Because [deprecated and obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?#remarks) in addition to be untyped and useless to use: *We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List<T>class. The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance.*"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayList vs List<> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp) and [Why isn't ArrayList marked "Obsolete"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063156/why-isnt-arraylist-marked-obsolete) and [What is the difference between an Array, ArrayList and a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020000/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-arraylist-and-a-list/32020072) and [C# objects in arrayLists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367524/c-sharp-objects-in-arraylists)

Answer (score -1):

Based on your requirement I think the below code will work for you.

```
        ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
        Product prod1 = new Product();
        prod1.addProduct();
        arrList.Add(prod1);
        Product prod2 = new Product();
        prod2.addProduct();
        arrList.Add(prod2)
```

I would suggest using List as it is generic. You can find more about ArrayList Vs List here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: But in this way I have to make the objects inside the class.